# fwrite seems to work, memcpy fails

Tags: c, string, io

I am not sure what is going on. Something related with buffering. The ... code ...

```
if (data->inbound){
//fwrite(buf, res, 1, stdout); //data->inbound);
char tmp[SOAP_BUFLEN+1];
memset(tmp,0,SOAP_BUFLEN+1);
if(len>0) {
    memcpy(tmp, buf, minim(SOAP_BUFLEN,len) );
    tmp[minim(SOAP_BUFLEN,len)] = '\0'; 
    printf("%s\n",tmp);
    //printf("-----------------\n");
}
```

when I use fwrite I see the output with no problems. When I use memcpy I see duplicate entries in the output? Do I need to fflush something?

At the end of the printf statement I see a portion of the tmp to be repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using different length values for fwrite vs memcpy. Based on the code (and commented out code) here, memcpy uses the lesser of `len` or `SOAP_BUFLEN`. fwrite uses `res * 1`. So I'd bet `len != res`.